# Get users posts on Mastodon via API using curl?

Tags: curl, mastodon

I am trying to get the posts of a user using curl from a mastodon server. So I created an api key on the server the user is on and I tried the following;

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer KEY" "https://mastodon.social/api/v1/statuses/:Tweakers"
```

It returns me:

> {"error":"Record not found"}

I also tried this;

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer KEY" "https://mastodon.social/api/v1/statuses/Tweakers"
```

But I get the same error.. what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The API path `/api/v1/statuses/` takes the ID of a specific status, not a username.

You need to call `/api/v1/accounts/{user_id}/statuses` to get posts for a user. This means that first, you need to convert the username to an ID; and then call the API to get statuses.

The syntax would be something like this (minus the specific curl call and authorization header)

- Call `/api/v1/accounts/lookup?acct={user}` to get the ID.
- Call `/api/v1/accounts/{user_id}/statuses` to get an array of statuses for the account.